# Tinymce and javascript - PHP Validation

Tags: php, javascript, validation, tinymce

I'm using Tinymce on my blog writing, but there seems to be a problem when using htmlspecialchars with PHP. All my

tags etc, shows up, and i want the styling of the P tag. Is there any way i can fix this? if i remote htmlspecialchars the site will be open for XSS etc, cause of javascript.

Dose anyone have a similar problem? and know how i can fix this? maybe remove some TinyMCE valdiation stuff or something?

Answer (score 2):

I use also TiniMCE. I use nothing but the below codes, which helps me.

```
$allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img>';
$allowedTags.='<li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del>';  
$new_msg = strip_tags(stripslashes($_POST['msg']), $allowedTags);// Posted data from tiniMCE text area
```

Try this above. This is save from XSS or other attack

Answer (score 1):

If you allow user to use TinyMCE , then you must remove all style of HTML tag and script . Then save direct to database , don't need to use htmlspecialchars.

If only a you can post then you don't need sanitize anything .

Comment: Removing all tags and script? ok, please tell me more about this. First, you don't need a script tag for running javascript code. Also, if i remove all html tags, whats then the point of using tinymce?

Comment: You remove style like this : style="font-size:13px"

Comment: and this would help why? as i said, whats the point of using tinymce then?

Comment: If you allow user post a page. It is complicate matter , User can style for HTML tag then they will can break your website layout .Or you must code allow valid style as color , font-size but you still must remove other style as height, width. You can use TinyMCE's BBcode plugin like as forums to allow user style  their post.

Comment: I'm asking why this is happening, not what i should do. But how i can fix the problem. Please stop spamming comments that doesn't have anything to do with my question. I'm asking why htmlspecialchars is doing this, and you keep talking about some crap i don't care about..

Comment: You can't use htmlspecialchars  if you sanitize data. And you is person type that make me annoy most in world. Easy to insult everyone.